# Hash::check always return false when compare password

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I passed password that inserted from form (confirm_password) that i want to check through

```
$.ajax({
                url: "{{url('account/password_verification')}}",
                method: "POST",
                //data: new FormData(this),
                data:"current_password="+current_password,
                dataType: 'JSON',
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(response) {
                        if(response.success) {
                            showMessage("error", response.message);
                        } else {
                            showMessage("error", response.message);
                        }
                    }
            });
```

After, I checked this confirm_password and user password. But, I have false output when use Hash::check()

```
public function password_verification(Request $request){
    $verify_password = $request->current_password;
    $password = Auth::user()->password;
    if (Hash::check($verify_password,$password)) {
        $res['success'] = true;
        $res['message'] = "Success";
        return response($res);
    }else{
        $res['success'] = false;
        $res['message'] = "Error";
        return response($res);
    }
}
```

When I input 111111 in current_password, I checked $encrypted_verify_password and $password.
$encrypted_verify_password = $2y$10$w0c./s4rwd.aTE99bdCf.O4a7fvDFERZ2isww.9QYvDZHYmFRDohu (its value changed when recall this fuction)
$password = $2y$10$mw3Wupj5nCYGJPnQIT53QuDzkxka//sncbpG8nfdF/2FOjQOsK3Au

What is solution?

Comment: Have you double-checked `$verify_password` is `111111`? It might be something as simple as `$request->current_password` not containing what you think it does.

Comment: There might be an issue with the Hash in the database. Open up a `php artisan tinker` session, and do `Hash::check('111111', Hash::make('111111'));` and see what it says. If that returns `true`, then `$user->password` doesn't contain a valid hash, or the hashed value of `$user->password` is not `111111`.